# Can PowerApps create an editable table? (both can add rows and columns)

Tags: powerapps

I search on the web and found a solution to add rows to a table in PowerApps (1-dimension), but I want to add a button to let users can add columns as well to make the table dynamically (2-dimension), are there any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a dataset of N x M dimensions, where N is your Column Count and M your Row Count.

Now, in order to increase the M-dimension, you can simple let a user click on a button for example to Collect an empty row to a datasat/collection to expand the M-size.

The N-Dimension requires more information. Is the table connected to a data source? If yes, you need functionality to add a column to your data source.

If it is only a local table, you can have a button that adds a column to the already existing collection with the AddColumns functions for example.

This is one option, there are loads of different ones.